# Windows 10 and new hardware

Tags: cpu, motherboard, windows-10

I recently upgraded my computer to Windows 10 from Windows 7.

I am now thinking about installing a new motherboard and processor. Will this require me to purchase a new version of Windows, or will I be able to run my current installation with the new hardware?

Comment: Are you wondering about your Windows key being tied to your hardware id's and if swapping a few pieces out will require a new activation key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid potential problems, you should format your computer and do a fresh clean install.
Windows You might like the new hardware, or may not, but probably "be aware" of changing hardware and some messages ... The fact is that I have not tried it, but do not expect anything good.

I'll say again, format the hard drive and do a clean install, you will save headaches.

[EDIT]

From [infopackets.com](https://www.infopackets.com/news/9639/how-clean-install-windows-10-using-windows-7-8-license)

> Rumor has it that in order to do a clean install -and- retain your free license to Windows 10, you must first install Windows 10 using an in-place upgrade; this is done from within an existing Windows desktop environment via "Get Windows 10 app". After that, you can then do a clean install using a Windows 10 DVD as many times as you want.
>
> The license for Windows 10 will be valid for the life of the device, and any subsequent clean installs will automatically register with Microsoft without requiring you to enter a serial number ever again. The free Windows 10 license is valid providing that you don't make any major hardware changes (such as a new motherboard, which technically constitutes a new computer). A new hard drive, for example, is not a major hardware change. Therefore the free Windows 10 license is tied to specific hardware (such as **motherboard, CPU, RAM**, etc).

So, no, you lose your "free" license with a major upgrade like the one you asking...

Comment: So, I guess what I was asking is that if this is possible with my upgrade version of Windows 10

Comment: Sure, you need a DVD or USB stick, to burn image file of Windows 10, and install it. In Google you have hundreds of tutorials and manuals. I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't do this when I upgraded from windows 7 with the free upgrade to Windows 10. I'm not entirely sure why I'd be able to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the motherboard is the real part Microsoft considers a 'new device'. You'll have to buy a new copy of Windows 10, or try your luck with the phone activation spitting out a free code for you.

> **Q:** What happens if I change the hardware configuration of my Windows 10 device?
>   A: If the hardware configuration of your Windows 10 device changes significantly (e.g. motherboard change) Windows may require re-activation on the device. This is the same experience as prior versions of Windows (e.g. Windows 7 and Windows 8.1).   The free upgrade offer will not apply to activation of Windows 10 in such scenarios where hardware changes reset Activation.

SOURCE: Straight from Microsoft themselves -  [Link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/reinstalling-windows-10-after-upgrade/578d0b7f-57e4-4893-b9d1-6cfac0d6290a)

Answer (score 0):

Had that fear too. I didn´t know if Windows 10 would run smoothly on my system so i entered Windows Insider to try preliminar first. Once installed the final version, activation happens automatically if connected to the internet. **Then, if you change the motherboard, you can´t actívate the same installed Windows 10 copy again. That´s what they say.**

[Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/reinstalling-windows-10-after-upgrade/578d0b7f-57e4-4893-b9d1-6cfac0d6290a?auth=1)

Of course, if you are not connected, activation will not take place, but you will not be able to install the latest drivers so you can´t take advantage of many improvements. :-(

Instead you can try readyboost or add/change RAM, if it is a matter of performance. I think that, as in the previous Windows versions, they let you changing the graphics too. Try asking them directly.

Comment: Hi sarakusta. Can you edit your answer to clarify what part of it is important, as it seems to be *"If u change the motherboard u can´t activate it again."*

Answer (score -1):

For you to change hardware especially a motherboard and processor it is best to do a fresh install of the OS to your drive. Unless you purchased and upgrade for Windows 10 it would best to do the following.

- Back up data
- If your on Windows 10 already make a DVD or USB Flash drive with the appropriate version of Windows you had on your computer when you got it (Home/Professional/Ultimate N) using the **[Media Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)**.
- Put in new hardware
- Install Windows 7/8** with the recovery media you got with your machine.
- Make sure network drivers are installed and connected to internet
- Do your upgrade to Windows 10 from the DVD, USB Flash you created or from the internet tool on the system tray.
- Install drivers for all devices with Windows 10 drivers.

If you purchased a copy of Windows 10

- Backup Data
- Do fresh install of Windows 10
- Install Windows 10 Drivers for your devices
- Put your data back on the machine.

Best thing about OS architecture for all versions of Windows from Vista up is that you can use any driver from Vista and up if you can't find a Windows 10 driver.

When that is done put your data back on when you have no problems with drivers or with Windows updates and enjoy. This should require NO purchase of new OS as long as you use the serial number on the machine or sticker that came with your Version of windows 7/8 that was installed on the machine you got with it.

**NOTE: Upgrade to 10 will not work with Windows Enterprise/RT.